Icosahedron missing triangles
I'm trying to create an icosahedron (I've been trying to figure this out for about a week).
Basically, I followed this article to create an Icosahedron mesh in code, and the positions of the vertices are correct, but there aren't enough triangles in the mesh (there are some weird gaps - I'll attach a photo of what I mean).
package com.origin.hexasphere.geometry;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class Hexasphere
{
    private Array<Point> points;
    private Array<Face> faces;
    private Model model;

    public Hexasphere()
    {
        points = new Array<Point>(true, 12);
        faces = new Array<Face>(true, 20);
        //createIco1();
        //createIco2();
        //createIco3();
        createIco4();
    }

    //Based on this article: http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html
    /*public void createIco1()
    {
        float tao = (float) (1 + Math.sqrt(5d)) / 2f; //MathUtils.PI / 2;
        //int offset = 0; //Because 4 = the number of color floats.
        float defaultSize = 1f; //Was 100f

        points.add(new Point(-1,  tao,  0, Color.RED));
        points.add(new Point( 1,  tao,  0, Color.GREEN));
        points.add(new Point(-1, -tao,  0, Color.BLUE));
        points.add(new Point( 1, -tao,  0, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        points.add(new Point( 0, -1,  tao, Color.RED));
        points.add(new Point( 0,  1,  tao, Color.GREEN));
        points.add(new Point( 0, -1, -tao, Color.BLUE));
        points.add(new Point( 0,  1, -tao, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        points.add(new Point( tao,  0, -1, Color.RED));
        points.add(new Point( tao,  0,  1, Color.GREEN));
        points.add(new Point(-tao,  0, -1, Color.BLUE));
        points.add(new Point(-tao,  0,  1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));

        //Don't forget to add these faces to the faces array, or you'll be wondering why tf this isn't working.
        // 5 faces around point 0
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 11, 5, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 5, 1, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 1, 7, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 7, 10, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 10, 11, false));

        // 5 adjacent faces
        faces.add(new Face(this, 1, 5, 9, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 5, 11, 4, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 11, 10, 2, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 10, 7, 6, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 7, 1, 8, false));

        // 5 faces around point 3
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 9, 4, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 4, 2, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 2, 6, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 6, 8, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 8, 9, false));

        // 5 adjacent faces
        faces.add(new Face(this, 4, 9, 5, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 2, 4, 11, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 6, 2, 10, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 8, 6, 7, false));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 9, 8, 1, false));
    }*/

    //https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2003/fall/23700/docs/handout-04.pdf
    public void createIco4()
    {
        float t = (float)(1.0f + Math.sqrt(5.0f)) / 2.0f;
        points.add(new Point(t, 1f, 0f));
        points.add(new Point(-t, 1f, 0f));
        points.add(new Point(t, -1f, 0f));
        points.add(new Point(-t, -1f, 0f));

        points.add(new Point(1f, 0f, t));
        points.add(new Point(1f, 0f, -t));
        points.add(new Point(-1f, 0f, t));
        points.add(new Point(-1f, 0f, -t));

        points.add(new Point(0f, t, 1f));
        points.add(new Point(0f, -t, 1f));
        points.add(new Point(0f, t, -1f));
        points.add(new Point(0f, -t, -1f));

        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 8, 4));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 5, 10));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 2, 4, 9));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 2, 11, 5));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 1, 6, 8));

        faces.add(new Face(this, 1, 10, 7));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 9, 6));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 7, 11));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 0, 10, 8));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 1, 8, 10));

        faces.add(new Face(this, 2, 9, 11));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 3, 9, 11));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 4, 2, 0));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 5, 0, 2));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 6, 1, 3));

        faces.add(new Face(this, 7, 3, 1));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 8, 6, 4));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 9, 4, 6));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 10, 5, 7));
        faces.add(new Face(this, 11, 7, 5));
    }

    public ModelInstance createModel()
    {
        //new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
        //                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE),
        //                    new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, ShaderProgram.NORMAL_ATTRIBUTE)
        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        MeshBuilder b = new MeshBuilder();
        b.begin(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked);
        for(int i = 0; i < points.size; i++)
        {
            Point point = points.get(i);
            b.vertex(point.getPosition().x, point.getPosition().y, point.getPosition().z);
            //b.vertex(point.getPosition().x, point.getPosition().y, point.getPosition().z,
                //point.getColor().r, point.getColor().g, point.getColor().b, point.getColor().a);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < faces.size; i++)
        {
            b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx1());
            b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx2());
            b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx3());
        }
        Mesh mesh = b.end();
        modelBuilder.begin();
        modelBuilder.part("world", mesh, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, new Material());
        this.model = modelBuilder.end();
        return new ModelInstance(model);
    }

    public Point getPointAt(int index)
    {
        return points.get(index);
    }

    public void debugMesh()
    {
        String vertsDebug = "";
        String facesDebug = "";
        for(Point p : points)
        {
            vertsDebug += "point [" + p.getPosition().toString() + "]\n";
        }
        for(Face f : faces)
        {
            facesDebug += "face [" + f.toString() + "]\n";
        }
        Gdx.app.log("Vertices", "");
    }
}

The above code is producing the following output:


The above is my actual code, but just using the following vertex/index arrays to re-create the mesh would produce the same output (I'm including some simple arrays for your convenience in re-creating my problem).
    float[] verts = new float[]
    {
        t, 1f, 0f,
        -t, 1f, 0f,
        t, -1f, 0f,
        -t, -1f, 0f,

        1f, 0f, t,
        1f, 0f, -t,
        -1f, 0f, t,
        -1f, 0f, -t,

        0f, t, 1f,
        0f, -t, 1f,
        0f, t, -1f,
        0f, -t, -1f
    };
    
    short[] indices = new short[]
    {
        0, 8, 4,
        0, 5, 10,
        2, 4, 9,
        2, 11, 5,
        1, 6, 8,

        1, 10, 7,
        3, 9, 6,
        3, 7, 11,
        0, 10, 8,
        1, 8, 10,

        2, 9, 11,
        3, 9, 11,
        4, 2, 0,
        5, 0, 2,
        6, 1, 3,

        7, 3, 1,
        8, 6, 4,
        9, 4, 6,
        10, 5, 7,
        11, 7, 5
    };


You are passing a VertexAttributes.Usage flag as a value for primitiveType in your call to modelBuilder.part.
modelBuilder.part("world", mesh, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, new Material());

The 3rd parameter of that method is supposed to be a OpenGL primitive type such as GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN.
When you are passing VertexAttributes.Usage.Position you are passing the value 1 which corresponds to the primitive type GL_LINES, but you are building your mesh using faces (i.e. triangles) so it doesn't make sense.
If you change your call to modelBuilder.part and pass GL_TRIANGLES instead your icosahedron will look correct.

In the example above I have added colors to the vertexes and added a normal so that some shading could be applied as I think it is easier to see the shape then.
Complete source code for the above animation is
package com.bornander.gdxsandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.DelaunayTriangulator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.DistanceJointDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.RevoluteJointDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.joints.WeldJointDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.MeshBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class SandboxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    public static class Hexasphere
    {
        public static class Point
        {
            public Vector3 position;

            public Point(float x, float y, float z) {
                position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
            }

            public Vector3 getPosition() { return position; }
        }

        public static class Face {
            public final short index1;
            public final short index2;
            public final short index3;

            public Face(Hexasphere hexasphere, int index1, int index2, int index3) {
                this.index1 = (short)index1;
                this.index2 = (short)index2;
                this.index3 = (short)index3;
            }

            public short getIdx1() { return index1; }
            public short getIdx2() { return index2; }
            public short getIdx3() { return index3; }
        }

        private Array<Hexasphere.Point> points;
        private Array<Hexasphere.Face> faces;
        private Model model;

        public Hexasphere()
        {
            points = new Array<Hexasphere.Point>();
            faces = new Array<Hexasphere.Face>();
            createIco4();
        }


        public void createIco4()
        {
            float t = (float)(1.0f + Math.sqrt(5.0f)) / 2.0f;
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(t, 1f, 0f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(-t, 1f, 0f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(t, -1f, 0f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(-t, -1f, 0f));

            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(1f, 0f, t));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(1f, 0f, -t));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(-1f, 0f, t));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(-1f, 0f, -t));

            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(0f, t, 1f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(0f, -t, 1f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(0f, t, -1f));
            points.add(new Hexasphere.Point(0f, -t, -1f));

            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 0, 8, 4));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 0, 5, 10));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 2, 4, 9));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 2, 11, 5));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 1, 6, 8));

            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 1, 10, 7));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 3, 9, 6));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 3, 7, 11));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 0, 10, 8));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 1, 8, 10));

            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 2, 9, 11));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 3, 9, 11));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 4, 2, 0));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 5, 0, 2));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 6, 1, 3));

            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 7, 3, 1));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 8, 6, 4));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 9, 4, 6));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 10, 5, 7));
            faces.add(new Hexasphere.Face(this, 11, 7, 5));
        }

        public ModelInstance createModel()
        {
            ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
            MeshBuilder b = new MeshBuilder();
            Color[] colors = new Color[] {
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.RED,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.BROWN,
                Color.CHARTREUSE,
                Color.CORAL,
                Color.CYAN,
                Color.DARK_GRAY,
                Color.FIREBRICK,
                Color.FOREST,
                Color.GOLD,
                Color.LIME,
                Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
                Color.OLIVE,
                Color.SKY,
                Color.SALMON
            };

            b.begin(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal |VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorUnpacked);
            for(int i = 0; i < points.size; i++)
            {
                Hexasphere.Point point = points.get(i);

                b.vertex(
                    point.getPosition(),
                    point.getPosition(),
                    colors[i],
                    new Vector2(1, 1)
                );
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < faces.size; i++)
            {
                b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx1());
                b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx2());
                b.index(faces.get(i).getIdx3());
            }
            Mesh mesh = b.end();
            modelBuilder.begin();
            modelBuilder.part("world", mesh,  GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.WHITE)));
            this.model = modelBuilder.end();
            return new ModelInstance(model);
        }
    }


    private Model model;
    private ModelBatch batch;
    private PerspectiveCamera cam;
    private ModelInstance modelInstance;
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        cam = cam = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        cam.position.set(4, 4, 4);
        cam.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        cam.near = 1.0f;
        cam.far = 300;
        cam.update();

        environment = new Environment();
        environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));


        this.batch = new ModelBatch();

        Hexasphere hs = new Hexasphere();
        modelInstance = hs.createModel();


        ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
        model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f,
            new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.RED)),
            VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
    }


    float angle = 0.0f;
    @Override
    public void render() {
        cam.update();
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        angle += 90.0 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        modelInstance.transform.setToRotation(Vector3.Y, angle);
        batch.begin(cam);
        batch.render(modelInstance, environment);
        batch.end();
    }
}


I've spent the last 4 days trying to solve this. I've lost at least 6-8 hours of sleep to this bug. I've tried just about every variation of vertices/indices that makes mathematical sense. You have no idea how thankful I am.

Dude, that comment made my day, @Jax :)
I am happy to have been able to assist you.
